# Series with exponential upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, exponential-sum

Let $K > 0$. Is it then true that there is some constant $C$ independent of $K$ such that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2^n K} \leq C e^{-K/C}$$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: i dont think so

Answer (score 1):

No.  If it were true, we would have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2^n K} < C,\ K>0$$because $e^{-K/C}<1.$  This is not true, since by letting $K\to0+,$ we can make the sum of the first $n$ terms of the left-hand side approach $n$ as nearly as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes sense. Do you think the inequality would hold if I bound K away from 0. So let's say $K \geq K_0 > 0$?

Comment: Not sure.  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Actually, I think according to the site rules, you should ask this as  another question.  It's probably a good idea anyway, to attract more attention.